# How to get each day's information using group by keyword in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by

I'm new in mysql and I'm currently having an issue with a query. I need to get an average duration for each activity each day within a week. The date format is like: '2000-01-01 01:01:01', but I want to get rid of the 01:01:01 thing and only care about the date. How do I do that?

The table is something like this:

```
record_id   int(10)      NOT NULL,
activity_id varchar(100) NOT NULL,
start_time  datetime     NOT NUll,
end_time    datetime     NOT NULL,
duration    int(10)      NOT NULL;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following

```
select activity_id, dayofweek(datetime) as day, avg(duration) as average
from table_name  where datetime between start_date and end_date
group by activity_id,dayofweek(datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding, you want to group by the different activity times and see the average days between the start and end of each activity. This should do it for you.

```
SELECT activity_id, avg(DATEDIFF(end_time, start_time)) AS Average 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY activity_id, DAYOFWEEK(start_time)
```

Edit: Misunderstood, you want it broken down by the day as well, so this should pull each group, broken down by the day of the week that the start_time falls on, and then the average days between start_time and end_time.

Comment: @dazhuangcao: Right, missed that the first time, but I went back and edited it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what I need is: average duration for each activity each day within a week. The start/end time are just time stamps to record the date of each activity. My rough thought was: SELECT activity_id, avg(duration) FROM table GROUP BY start_time HAVING start_time BETWEEN(insert two dates here);

Comment: So... I'm not understanding, I'm grouping by activity, and then by the day of the week the activity started. Is the duration somehow different than the end - start time...? Also, if you wanted to limit the weeks you pull out, do that with `WHERE ...`.

Comment: The result I'm expecting is: date('yyyy-mm-dd'), activity_id, average_time. Each activity is only a few minutes by the way, so there will be multiple activities per day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [date_format(end_time, '%Y%m%d')](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to convert it to a sortable value by day.  Put that in the group by expression, and that should do what you want.